# Append multiple text files into single file and Rename the file

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Hello I have multiple text files in one location and they have names as shown below:-

`A_L_PRTD_021345.txt` , `A_L_PRTD_432124`  and so on...

I want to append the contents  into single file and want to rename the single file as `L_PRTD_Currentdate>.txt`

How is it possible?
Can you please show some code for it?

Comment: The way to do it would be read from each file and append the content in the desired filename. Search a bit about how to read and write files with c#. This is not that difficult a task. Sytem.IO.File class will be of your use. Try writing your own code.

Comment: System `copy` command already does that - either don't reinvent wheel OR show some serious effort in solving it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First read each file using `File.ReadAllLines(fileName) ;`
Then create a single file and append the contents of other files in it

```
    string[] contents1 = File.ReadAllLines(fileName1) ; 
    string[] contents2 = File.ReadAllLines(fileName2) ; 
    File.Create(newFileNameHere) ; 
    File.WriteAllLines(newFileNameHere, contents1) ;
    File.AppendAllLines(newFileNameHere, contents2) ;
```

and so on ... 
Check the following documentation of the functions, if you need help:-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can you please show me some code ?

Comment: I have added some code.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it is solving your problem

Comment: It was not solving. I am writing my own . Thanks!

Comment: But it is is solving , you wanted to read and transfer all the contents of two files into the thirdt file. right?

Comment: It does solve the question that you ask. Please explain why it does not.

Comment: Actually I want to append multiple files and not two files only and it will check for duplicate rows inside the file and if any duplicate rows will be there then it will remain the distinct rows only . It will be for multiple file and not for just two files.

Comment: @DeboPam we can only provide you with basic code, so that you start thinking in right direction, we cannot write the full code for you!